# How to lighten / darken a linear gradient properly?

Tags: css, sass, user-experience, linear-gradients

I'm trying to lighten / darken my button background when `:hover` on.

I tried different style like

```
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-blend-mode:darken;
```

But it doesn't work like i want.
I want a really really light lighten and same for the darken.

```
 background: linear-gradient(173deg, rgba(255,121,218,1) 0%, rgba(214,108,219,1) 39%, rgba(171,94,220,1) 85%, rgba(155,89,220,1) 100%);
```

here is my baby :
[image: My btn]

Thanks for your help community <3

Comment: apply another layer on the top of the gradient

Comment: decrease the value of alpha in rgba()

Answer (score 1):

You can use lighten inside linear-gradient like that:

```
background: linear-gradient(
  356deg,
  lighten(*your color*, 5%) 0%,
  lighten(*your color*, 5%) 33%,
  lighten(*your color*, 5%) 100%
);
```

Exemple here: https://codepen.io/perpel_/pen/LYyJWpp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a linear gradient white with opacity.

```css
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)), *your color of the btn*;
```

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this problem and was looking for a solution.
In the end, I decided to use different variables based on perpel's solution

```css
/* gradient colors */
@color1: #8f23a2;
@color2: #c1276a;
@color3: #dc8f41;

@darken :10%;
@lighten :10%;

@my-gradient: linear-gradient(to bottom, @color1, @color2  50%, @color3);

@my-gradient-darken: linear-gradient(
                                to bottom,
                                 darken(@color1, @darken),
                                 darken(@color2, @darken) 50%,
                                 darken(@color3, @darken)
                                 );

@my-gradient-lighten: linear-gradient(
                                to bottom,
                                 lighten(@color1, @lighten),
                                 lighten(@color2, @lighten) 50%,
                                 lighten(@color3, @lighten)
                                 );
```